# UCMA 3.0 Sample Learning Project

Tags: lync-2010, ucma

I am new to UCMA 3.0 (and new to Lync server as well) and want to get a feeling about how to talk to Lync 2010 server through UCMA. I want to have something quick and dirty, such as a step-by-step tutorial showing me how to set up the development environment, writing the least UCMA code to achieve a simple task, such as connect to the Lync server, get the list of all the users with their presence information, and print the results out to console. The purpose is to get a proof of concept about how UCMA works against Lync server.

I already have a Lync 2010 server setup and running with some testing users created, I also downloaded and installed UCMA 3.0 SDK on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine which also has Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with .NET 3.5 SP1. So, all hardware and software are ready.

Any advice, links, or even better direct step-by-step answers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have found this book at Amazon: Professional Unified Communications Development with Microsoft Lync Server 2010. It seems to be the bible for the UCMA 3.0 development. I have ordered it already :-)

Comment: Also found some sample applications installed under the UCMA 3.0 SDK directory. Trying it...

Comment: Yes - it is the bible. Also (shamelss plug) keep an eye on my blog http://www.codelync.com as i'll be covering this sort of material over the coming weeks. Michael Greenlee's blog is a great source of in-depth UCMA info http://blog.greenl.ee/

Comment: Hello Paul, no shame as all :-) I have already read all your answers in stackoverflow and all your blog entries. I am glad to get the answer so promptly from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently posted an answer in a technet forum [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsucintegration/thread/cbd73f23-cf46-4291-b2ec-d25f86dcae75/#b9de55cc-86cf-4ce8-afd1-1d90bd417753) that might help - sorry if you are the same person :)

Basically, it reads:

There is no single article that explains the entire process, as far as I know. You'll need to read around quite a bit.

There are no UCMA application templates in VS (there are for client-side development with the Lync SDK, but not for UCMA yet). In your console app, you'll just need to add a reference to C:\Program Files\Microsoft UCMA 3.0\SDK\Core\Bin\Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.dll.

You'll need to undertand the difference between User endpoints and Application endpoints, more info in the SDK documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh347238.aspx (you'll need a User endpoint)

There is some information about fetching contacts and groups here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh347376.aspx

Deploying a UCMA app can be long-winded. The best place to start learning about this is in the SDK - the articles in this section from the SDK documentation should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh347291.aspx

Also, check out the sample applications in the SDK.

Comment: I am not that person :-) Thank you very much for the information. I am currently trying to get the sample application in the Core SDK up and running in my VS 2008. I have hit a problem and an trying to figure it out (the target principal name is incorrect, ). As you have pointed out, I have been suspected that the initial pain point would be the deploy/setup part of the development environment.